# Как вывести все результаты с цикла?

Tags: php, циклы, for

Как вывести все результаты с цикла?

Пример:

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $data = array('ФИО1', 'ФИО2', 'ФИО3');
    print_r($data);
}

print_r($data);

print_r($data); в цикле выводит 10 раз $data
print_r($data); за циклом выводит только последний результат $data
```

мне нужно для дальнейшей обработки и сохранения в эксель файл обращаться к переменной со всеми данными.

А если в цикле сделать запись массива в mysql и уже оттуда брать данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю, что правильно понял вопрос, но если требуется сохранить данные, записаные в цикле, то:

```
$data = array();
for($i = 1;$ <=10; $i++){
    array_push($data, 'ФИО1', 'ФИО2', 'ФИО3');
}

print_r($data);
```

Если же нужен двумерный массив, то:

```
$data = array();
for($i = 1;$i <= 10;$i++){
    $data[$i] = array('ФИО1', 'ФИО2', 'ФИО3');
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет смысла писать в mysql, достаточно переменной-массива:

```
$data = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $data[] = array('ФИО1', 'ФИО2', 'ФИО3');
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать отдельную переменную для хранения всего результата вывода таким образом, что каждую итерацию в этой переменной будет увеличиваться массив (хотя может быть и строка) значений.

Например:

```
$data = array();
$data_all = array();
for($i=1;$i <= 10; $i++) { 
       $data = array('ФИО1', 'ФИО2', 'ФИО3');
       print_r($data);
       array_push($data, ('ФИО1', 'ФИО2', 'ФИО3'));
}
```

Проверьте, возможно потребуется внесение массива в массив.

Comment: У вас array_push делает не то, что Вы ожидаете. Вероятно, стоит убрать скобки.